# Emacs custom command help

Tags: commands

I am pretty new to Emacs.  Could someone please help me to write a custom command which I can add to my init file? It would do the following:

1. Split the screen vertically to get two windows.
2. Check if a buffer named '* ansi-term *' (without spaces) exists. If so, it would open this buffer in the one of vertically split windows.
3. If a buffer with such a name doesn't exist it would run command `ansi-term` (ignoring all prompting) to start a new terminal instance in one of the vertically windows.

Comment: This is not clear: `buffer named '* ansi-term *' (without spaces)`.  Please clarify. (Also, please say what you've tried so far and what kind of "help" you need.)

Comment: I'm guessing the OP added spaces to avoid some effect of the markup, but as far as I can tell the name of the buffer is `*ansi-term*` - indeed, without spaces.

Comment: Thank you, guys. Solutiion from xuchunyang works great!

Comment: If you're interested in learning elisp, I highly recommend reading "An Introduction to Programming Emacs Lisp".  You may already have it.  Type `C-h i` and look for `Emacs Lisp Intro`.  Otherwise, you can read it online.  It's a super fun read! https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a command which might do what you want:

```el
(defun my-ansi-term ()
  (interactive)
  (select-window (split-window-right))
  (let ((buffer (get-buffer "*ansi-term*")))
    (if buffer
        (switch-to-buffer buffer)
      (ansi-term shell-file-name))))
```

If you're not happy with the window layout, try to figure it out by yourself, try `switch-to-buffer-other-window` etc.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Works just as expected! Such a time saver!